# Changing View on List Item Click

Tags: android, list, android-listview, android-view

i have a `ListView` with a `onClicklListener`.

The `ListView` has a row `Layout` of say `/res/listitem_a`

now after an `onClickevent` of the any listitem , i want to change the layout of
only that listitem to say `/res/listitem_b..`

any help on how shall i proceed.

Comment: what you have tried.. ??

Answer (score 0):

Use BaseAdapter and modify in getView call.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null);
            // Creates a ViewHolder and store references to the two children views
            // we want to bind data to.
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        // Change text size
        holder.text.setTextAppearance(context,R.style.customStyle);

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView text;
    }
```

And **you can use position variable in getView call to change specific row**. Hope this help!!!

Comment: so where do u implement my second layout that has to be shown after onClick?

Comment: your second layout will be for Only one for Single raw right? you can manage your layout itself by above method. can you please specify what ou have implemented? so that it will be easy for us to give you suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ViewFlipper as layout of the rows. With ViewFlipper you can specify as many layouts as you want and flip among them when something happen (like a click event). [Here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/a-dog-limps-into-a-saloon-a-tutorial-on-androids-viewflipper-widget/634) is a good tutorial about ViewFlipper.

Moreover, you should implement a custom adapter, extending BaseAdapter, and overriding the getView method.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_row_layout, null);  //this will inflate the layout into each row
    }

    //from here on, assign the information to display to the layout widgets
```

Hope I've helped you.